# Windows Registry settings corresponding to PowerCfg.exe /setacvalueindex

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, powershell-3.0, powercfg

In my powershell script, I use

```
powercfg /setacvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da 0
```

I wanted to later verify if the above value has been set or not. 
How do i verify this ?

**I couldn't find any GET version of this SET command-option, like GETacvalueIndex ?**

or 
**is there any registry settings that gets set when we do this, so that I can verify it in windows registry ?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can use `PowerReadACValue`
（https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/powersetting/nf-powersetting-powerreadacvalue）

For example
(http://www.reza-aghaei.com/how-to-get-value-of-advanced-power-settings/)

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
static extern uint PowerGetActiveScheme(
    IntPtr UserRootPowerKey,
    ref IntPtr ActivePolicyGuid);
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
static extern uint PowerReadACValue(
    IntPtr RootPowerKey,
    ref Guid SchemeGuid,
    ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingGuid,
    ref Guid PowerSettingGuid,
    ref int Type,
    ref int Buffer,
    ref uint BufferSize);

public static void Foo()
{
    var activePolicyGuidPTR = IntPtr.Zero;
    PowerGetActiveScheme(IntPtr.Zero, ref activePolicyGuidPTR);

    var activePolicyGuid = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Guid>(activePolicyGuidPTR);
    var type = 0;
    var value = 0;
    var valueSize = 4u;
    PowerReadACValue(IntPtr.Zero, ref activePolicyGuid,
        ref GUID_SLEEP_SUBGROUP, ref GUID_STANDBY_TIMEOUT,
        ref type, ref value, ref valueSize);

    var message = $"Sleep after {value} seconds.";
}
```